# how can I filter dataset to a new dataset by map?

Tags: dataframe, dataset

I have DataFrame and an array

Input:

```
1. an array,array's length is uncertain.
array[eason,wency,kobe...]

2. dataframe like this:
    name   grade   
    eason    90
    evan     80
    wency    70
    elton    50  
    frank    90
    ...      ..
    kobe     90
```

output: according to the elements of array filter the input to this dataframe:

```
name   grade
eason   90
wency   70
kobe    90
...     ..
```

how can i get a new dataframe by map or other spark api?
Please, any Idea.

Comment: please add a language tag and explain a bit more clearly what the difference between your input and output should be

Comment: I agree, the inputs and outputs you've specified here look almost identical, and it's not clear what changes are intended.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the Spark DataFrame from the array as below:

```
scala> val arr = Array("eason", "wency", "elton", "kobe")
arr: Array[String] = Array(eason, wency, elton, kobe)
scala> val df = sc.parallelize(arr).toDF("name")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string]
scala> df.show()
+-----+
|name|
+-----+
|eason|
|wency|
|elton|
| kobe|
+-----+
```

Once the DataFrame is constructed from Array, you can join 2 DataFrames using the common name field.

Other DataFrame:

```
scala> otherDF.show()
+-----+-----+
| name|grade|
+-----+-----+
|eason|   90|
| evan|   80|
|wency|   70|
|elton|   50|
|frank|   90|
| kobe|   90|
+-----+-----+
```

Joining Two Dataframes using name field:

```
scala> val joinedDF = otherDF.join(df, "name")
joinedDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, grade: int]

scala>

scala> joinedDF.show()
+-----+-----+
| name|grade|
+-----+-----+
|eason|   90|
|wency|   70|
|elton|   50|
| kobe|   90|
+-----+-----+
```